# Updating based on checkbox selection

Tags: javascript, extjs

I placing some xml data in grid using extjs. Now I'm trying to build an update function,
that worked fine, however I'm trying first to extract the data to be updated, so that the user won't have to insert the whole data again.

I managed to extract the data depending on the position in the grid, but not on the selection of checkbox next to each entry in the grid.

Code:

```
if (btn.id == "btn_update") {
        var selection = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection();
        if(selection.length == 0){
            alert("Please select an item to update");
        } 
        else if(selection.length > 1){
            alert("Please only select one item to update");  
        }
        else{
            Ext.getCmp('update_name').setValue(gridStore.getAt(0).get("FirstName"));
            Ext.getCmp('update_lastname').setValue(gridStore.getAt(0).get("LastName"));
            Ext.getCmp('update_email').setValue(gridStore.getAt(0).get("Email"));
            winupdate.show();       
        }
    }
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Which version of ExtJs are you using? Which pattern (mvc, mvvm, no pattern)? Have you seen the xml reader? http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Xml

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you.

You can use **checkboxSelectionModel** in grid and when you click on checkbox **select** event will be fired and that will give you current record, index and many other.

```
xtype:'grid',
selModel: Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel',{
listeners: {
            select: function (el, record, index, eOpts) {
            //Get current record from record variable
         }
}
```